# Determine if a string starts with more letters of a given kind than the other

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
var s1 = "-Hello";
var s2 = "--Whats up?";
var s3 = "How you doing?";
```

How can I compare the strings, and ask the question; "is this string starting with more '-' than the other?".

Comment: I have tried very little. I am not sure where to start. Talked with the #javascript and #jquery channel, they suggested stackoverflow. I'm not looking for a complete answer, just what I should look for.

Comment: They suggested wrongly. You need a discussion, or mentoring. This is a programming Q&A. IRC was the right place to go (you didn't say which network); they were just trying to get rid of you.

Comment: So are you, trying to get rid of me. This question got an answer here, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: Many, many questions got answers here that were not supposed to be asked in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function count( str ){
   var match = str.match(/(-+)/);
   return match ? match[0].length : 0;
}

console.log( count("--qwerty") );
```

Or if you want to pass in the leading character

```
function count( char, str ){
   var newRE = new RegExp( "(" + char + "+)","" );
   var match = str.match( newRE );
   return match ? match[0].length : 0;
}

console.log( count("-", "--qwerty") );
```

Comment: Shouldn't that first regex be `/^(.)\1*/` (count the number of repetitions of whatever the first character is)?

Comment: The only type of char is '-' that I will look for, so it works for me with that regex.